# Why is Egoroff's theorem limited to finite measure spaces?

Tags: measure-theory

What would be an example of a sequence of functions which shows that the restriction to spaces of finite measure in Egoroff's theorem is necessary?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egorov's_theorem#Discussion_of_assumptions_and_a_counterexample

Comment: Just a suggestion: If you're going to keep posting so many questions in quick succession, all of which smell like homework then it would be a very nice treat if you shared a few thoughts on the matters. This might increase the willingness of people to spend some time answering your questions dramatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider $f_n(x) = \chi_{[n, n+1]}(x)$, where $\chi_A$ is the indicator (characteristic) function of $A$.